# Assuming that the relationship between unit price and quantity supplied is linear, derive the supply equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Suppliers of a certain brand of digital voice recorders will make $10000$ available in the market price if the unit price is set at $\$45$. At a unit price of $\$50$, $20,000$ units will be made available. Assuming that the relationship between unit price and quantity supplied is linear, derive the supply equation, and calculate how many units should be made available if the unit price is $\$70$.

**My Try :**(In short)

Since the relationship between unit price and quantity supplied is linear we let, the supply equation to be :
$$y=ax+b$$ where, $$y = \ \text{quantity supplied} \\
x = \ \text{unit price} \\
a, b \ \ \text{are constants to be determined}$$

Then according to the question we get,

$$ 20000 = 50a + b \\
10000 = 45a + b$$

Solving : $$ a = 2000 \\
b = -80000$$

Then the required equation is :
$$y = 2000x - 80000$$

And now for $x= 70$ we get $y= 60000$ from the equation.

Is my solution and interpretation of it is correct? I'm doing it for the first time.

Comment: +1 : to your question for good presentation and good work shown.  Independently, you nailed it.  Note that **if** you had only been asked for the supply at $\$70$, you could have avoided having to find the linear equation, and instead employed an *intuitive* shortcut: since the availability increases by $10000$ for each $\$5$ raise in price, increasing the price from $\$50$ to $\$70$ should result in a supply increase of $(4 \times 10000) = 40000~$ and $~40000 + 20000 = 60000.$